# Como utilizo a tecla F2 para abrir outro formulário?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho o seguinte código, mas esta habilitado a tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (13) para abrir o formulário, eu gostaria de habilitar o <kbd>F2</kbd>, já procurei tabelas ASCII por toda parte e não encontro o código desejado.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            //sua rotina aqui
            OPERACOES OP = new OPERACOES();
            OP.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Realmente tem que verificar o código da tecla e não tabela ASCII:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2) {
        //sua rotina aqui
        OPERACOES OP = new OPERACOES();
        OP.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/BindingF2.cs).

Comment: Com este comando que me passou ja tentei , qualquer botao que eu clico abre o formulario e não somente o F12.

Comment: Não, então você fez de outro jeito. Dê uma olhada em todo o código. Eu percebi que você não organiza bem o código, assim fica mais difícil entender o que está acontecendo, então o problema pode estar em outro lugar. Você pode postar o código que você tentou pra gente ver se tem algum erro nele. Mas tem que colocar o código real.

Comment: @user33133 se você clica e o formulário abre, então seu código não está vinculado a `_KeyPress` - está, provavelmente, no `_OnClick`.

Comment: @OnoSendai boa, eu nem me toquei que ele falou em *click* :)

Comment: @bigown a não ser que por botão o OP queira dizer tecla, aí pode ser o KeyPress sendo interpretado mesmo...

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa usar a propriedade `KeyCode` e compará-la com o [`Enum Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) para verificar qual a tecla que está sendo pressionada.

Exemplo:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs evt){
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
    {
        OPERACOES OP = new OPERACOES();
        OP.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Não esqueça que você precisa alterar a propriedade `KeyPreview` do form para `true`**

Comment: Ja usei o KeyDown, mas qualquer tecla abre o formulario e nao somente o F2.

Comment: Impossível. Você consegue debugar e ver qual o valor em `e.KeyCode`?

Answer (score 2):

A maneira ideal de processar eventos de teclado em um form onde o controle que recebe o evento é irrelevante (ou seja, o foco pode estar em qualquer controle presente no form) é via *override* do método `ProcessCmdKey` no form:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Você pressionou a tecla F2.");
        return true;    // Indica que o pressionar desta tecla 
                        // foi gerenciado aqui.
    }

    // Propaga o evento para o método da classe base
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData)
}
```

Fonte:
[How do I capture Keys.F1 regardless of the focused control on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951496/how-do-i-capture-keys-f1-regardless-of-the-focused-control-on-a-form)

Comment: O evento `KeyDown` do form não é disparado com o foco em qualquer controle também?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Eu acredito que sim, caso `KeyPreview = true;`. Entretanto, 2 pontos - `ProcessCmdKey` acontece antes na cascata de eventos, e este método guarante que você irá receber o evento mesmo que a propriedade KeyPreview seja alterada (acidentalmente ou não) para `False`.

Comment: Interessante. Principalmente o fato de `ProcessCmdKey` ser o primeiro a ser executado, não sabia disso.

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei uma lista indicando algumas teclas do teclado para usar no evento KeyUp, não conferi todas mas o "F2" funcionou.

Ai é só trocar no if.

Exemplo:

```
//Verificando se foi acionado a tecla F2

if(e.KeyChar == **113**){

//comandos

}
```

Segue a lista:

> 8: Coloca(’ [BACKSPACE] ‘);
>
> 9: Coloca(’ [TAB] ‘);
>
> 12: Coloca(’ [ALT] ‘);
>
> 13: Coloca(’ [ENTER] ‘);
>
> 16: Coloca(’ [SHIFT] ‘);
>
> 17: Coloca(’ [CONTROL] ‘);
>
> 18: Coloca(’ [ALT] ‘);
>
> 20: Coloca(’ [CAPS LOCK] ‘);
>
> 21: Coloca(’ [PAGE UP] ‘);
>
> 27: Coloca(’ [ESC] ‘);
>
> 33: Coloca(’ [PAGE UP] ‘);
>
> 34: Coloca(’ [PAGE DOWN] ‘);
>
> 35: Coloca(’ [END] ‘);
>
> 36: Coloca(’ [HOME] ‘);
>
> 37: Coloca(’ [SETA ESQUERDA] ‘);
>
> 38: Coloca(’ [SETA ACIMA] ‘);
>
> 39: Coloca(’ [SETA DIREITA] ‘);
>
> 40: Coloca(’ [SETA ABAIXO] ‘);
>
> 45: Coloca(’ [INSERT] ‘);
>
> 46: Coloca(’ [DEL] ‘);
>
> 91: Coloca(’ [WIN ESQUERDA] ‘);
>
> 92: Coloca(’ [WIN DIREITA] ‘);
>
> 93: Coloca(’ [MENU POP-UP] ‘);
>
> 96: Coloca(’0&8242;);
>
> 97: Coloca(’1&8242;);
>
> 98: Coloca(’2&8242;);
>
> 99: Coloca(’3&8242;);
>
> 100: Coloca(’4&8242;);
>
> 101: Coloca(’5&8242;);
>
> 102: Coloca(’6&8242;);
>
> 103: Coloca(’7&8242;);
>
> 104: Coloca(’8&8242;);
>
> 105: Coloca(’9&8242;);
>
> 106: Coloca(’ [NUM *] ‘);
>
> 107: Coloca(’ [NUM +] ‘);
>
> 109: Coloca(’ [NUM -] ‘);
>
> 110: Coloca(’ [NUM SEP. DECIMAL] ‘);
>
> 111: Coloca(’ [NUM /] ‘);
>
> 112: Coloca(’ [F1] ‘);
>
> 113: Coloca(’ [F2] ‘);
>
> 114: Coloca(’ [F3] ‘);
>
> 115: Coloca(’ [F4] ‘);
>
> 116: Coloca(’ [F5] ‘);
>
> 117: Coloca(’ [F6] ‘);
>
> 118: Coloca(’ [F7] ‘);
>
> 119: Coloca(’ [F8] ‘);
>
> 120: Coloca(’ [F9] ‘);
>
> 121: Coloca(’ [F10] ‘);
>
> 122: Coloca(’ [F11] ‘);
>
> 123: Coloca(’ [F12] ‘);
>
> 144: Coloca(’ [NUM LOCK] ‘);
>
> 186: Coloca(’Ç’);
>
> 187: Coloca(’=´);
>
> 188: Coloca(’,´);
>
> 189: Coloca(’-´);
>
> 190: Coloca(’.´);
>
> 191: Coloca(’;´);
>
> 192: Coloca(’ [APÓSTROFO] ‘);
>
> 193: Coloca(’/´);
>
> 194: Coloca(’ [NUM PONTO] ‘);
>
> 219: Coloca(’´’);
>
> 220: Coloca(’]´);
>
> 221: Coloca(’[´);
>
> 222: Coloca(’~´);
>
> 226: Coloca(’\´);